# Spring returns new instance each time I use instance variable

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

I got a wired problem.

Here is my object definition.

```
package unittest.prototypetest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("valObject")
@Scope("prototype")
public class ValueObject {
  private String value1;
  private String value2;

  //... getter and setter omitted.
}
```

And I defined the component scan tag as below:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="unittest" scoped-proxy="targetClass" />
```

Then I tried to get its instance via ApplicatioinContext,

```
//ApplicationContextHelper is a class written by me to easily create ApplicationContext
ValueObject valObject = ApplicationContextHelper.getBean("valObject");
valObject.setValue1("v1");
valObject.setValue2("v2");

System.out.println(valObject.getValue1());
System.out.println(valObject.getValue2());
```

The most wired result is shown below:

```
2013-01-15_14:04:02.245| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'valObject'
2013-01-15_14:04:02.246| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.valObject'
2013-01-15_14:04:02.246| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2013-01-15_14:04:02.250| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2013-01-15_14:04:02.250| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2013-01-15_14:04:02.252| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Finished creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.valObject'
2013-01-15_14:04:02.295| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.valObject'
2013-01-15_14:04:02.296| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Finished creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.valObject'
2013-01-15_14:04:02.296| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.valObject'
2013-01-15_14:04:02.296| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Finished creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.valObject'
null
2013-01-15_14:04:02.296| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.valObject'
2013-01-15_14:04:02.297| DEBUG | o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory | Finished creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.valObject'
null
```

You can see each time I use valObject instance, Spring did create a new instance for my access.
so that the system out prints null, although I set value.

Did I do something wrong ? Please advise, thanks a lot.

Comment: I have to mention that the problem is not I set "prototype". Please see the log, each time I call setValue() of the same valObject instance, Spring should not create a new instance!

Answer (score 0):

You have set the scope to prototype, wich is a non-singleton. Read more about it [here.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype)

Comment: I do want it is a "prototype", as you see my code example, it should remain the same instance, since I just asked it once.